# R: calling tsls() within a function does not recognize arguments?

Tags: r, function, arguments, scope

I'd like to call tsls() within a function, but for some reason it's not recognizing the arguments.  In a simplified example (below), the arguments Y1, Y2, X, Z are vectors in data-frame "data":

```
tslsex <- function(Y1,Y2,X,Z,data) {
  attach(data)
  results <- tsls(Y1 ~ cbind(Y2,X), ~ cbind(X,Z))
  detach(data)
  summary(results)
}
```

Calling the function:

```
tslsex(dependent,endogenous,cbind(control-1,control-2),instrument,dataframe)
```

Results in:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Y1' not found
```

Which is strange, because a similar use of lm() seems to work fine.  Anyone have any ideas on this?  I suspect it relates to the environment of the variables, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Thanks in advance.

andy

Comment: You passed the *contents* of Y1 as your first variable, but you want to pass the *name* "Y1" .  At least that's my guess. Take a look at `deparse(substitute(Y1))` as a way to keep the names themselves.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't know about those functions, actually.  Still can't get it to work when passing the string text itself, but I'll keep investigating.  What's strange is that lm() works fine, so the functions must handle arguments in different ways.  Still puzzled...